# php tell between function and string

Tags: php, function-pointers

is their a way to create an array that stores both strings and functions that generate strings?

```
<?php

function foo()
{
    return "calling foo()";
}


function bar()
{
    return "callin bar()";
}


$data = array();
$data[] = "foo";
$data[] = "bar";

foreach ($data as $element) {
    if (is_callable($element)) echo $element()."\n";
    else echo $element."\n";
}
```

will output:

```
calling foo()
calling bar()
```

is there some way to implement the array so that I get the output:

```
calling foo()
bar
```

something like

```
$data[] = &foo;
$data[] = "bar";

foreach ($data as $element) {
    if (is_callable($element) && !is_string($element)) return $element();
    else return $element;
}
```

Comment: You could store closure within the array, instead of strings that magically have other tasks

Comment: you could use objects that implement the `__toString()`-method

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need this, but the problem is that the way you are doing it they are always strings and if they are callable there is no way to differentiate.  How about using the key or something similar, since the array is ordered by the order of creation:

```
$data["foo"] = "foo";
$data[] = "bar";

foreach ($data as $key => $element) {
    if (is_callable($element) && is_string($key)) {
        echo $element()."\n";
    } else {
        echo $element."\n";
    }
}
```

Another possibility (there are many):

```
$data[]['fnc'] = "foo";
$data[]['str'] = "bar";

foreach ($data as $element) {
    if (isset($element['fnc']) && is_callable($element['fnc'])) {
        $element = $element['fnc'];
        echo $element()."\n";
    } else {
        echo $element['str']."\n";
    }
}
```

If you store code you could eval:

```
$data[] = "echo foo();";
$data[] = "echo 'bar';";

foreach ($data as $element) {
    eval($element);
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to the second option.